# I need a DNS longer that 40 characters

Tags: networking, dns, reverse-dns

I try to debug my reverse DNS request subroutine, and I need a DNS that's longer than 40 characters, because apparently that's how many bytes Dnsapi reserves in memory.

So I want to see what happens when NameHost in a PTR structure exceeds 40 bytes. Specifically, I expect that the reserved memory for the structure is going to be extended and padded with 0s, but I need to test that.

So does anyone know a DNS longer than 40 characters? Something like `verylonglabel1.verylonglabel2.example.com`.

Comment: I don't see the problem. I've just set up a reverse longer than 40 characters and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: Also see: [What is the real maximum length of a DNS name?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/04/12/10292868.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So does anyone know a dns longer than 40 characters?

No, but I typed [`world's longest domain name`](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=world's+longest+domain+name&aq=f&oq=world's+longest+domain+name&aqs=chrome.0.57j60l3j62.2556j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) into [Google](http://google.com) and found this:

```
www.thelongestdomainnameintheworldandthensomeandthensomemoreandmore.com
```

Now I do.

> 40 characters, because apparently that's how many bytes Dnsapi reserves in memory.

Noting that 40 characters is not necessarily 40 bytes (Unicode), you might want to [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682016(v=vs.85).aspx), I did and I couldn't find anything to suggest a 40 byte limit.

[This RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) doesn't seem to suggest any arbitrary limits on DNS records in this regard, at least from a cursory glance.

Comment: is not limited to 40 bytes, but if the dns is shorter than 40 characters, is stored in 40 bytes and padded with 0s at the end

Comment: @user1410908 Padding with `'0'` or padded with `NULL`? Because if it's padded with `NULL` you might not be looking at a 40 byte string, you might be looking at a buffer overflow. Surely it's just a null terminated string and you treat it as such?

Comment: I just tried your suggested domain, and a dns request returned 94.126.42.50, and when I did a reverse dns request (PTR) on this IP I get "seriously.nothingtoseehere.org" .. lol .. which is under 40 chars.

Comment: Just go down the list of Google results.

Comment: my scripting language (AHK) can't actually tell a difference between '0' and NULL. I'm reading byte by byte in memory and I see the entire structure .. there is no overflow

Comment: It's weird .. all the long domains return an IP, on which if I do a reverse dns it returns a different and shorter (under 40 chars) domain

Comment: AHK seems pretty flexible http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/80585-how-to-manipulate-binary-data-with-pointers/#entry86227 You can't compare it to `Chr(0)`?

Comment: This is what I get from memory 0x61:0x6D:0x65:0x6C:0x69:0x61:0x68:0x6F:0x75:0x73:0x65:0x2E:0x70:0x6C:0x75:0x73:0x2E:0x63:0x6F:0x6D:0x0:0x0:0x0:0x0:0x78:0xA1:0x1E:0x43:0x2D:0x59:, and if I call Chr(byte) on each byte : ameliahouse.plus.com\>FDŽ .. the 4 0s at the end seems to mark the end of the string

Comment: Surely the one `0x0` at the end is the last character plus one? It's a null terminated string.

Comment: This is what I'm not sure about, if it's a NULL terminated string or not. I'm not sure where I should stop reading . I'm afraid that at one point the string is not null terminated, and read more than I should. I'm not sure how the DNS_RECORD structure is stored in memory.

Comment: From it's usage [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/831226), `PTR.pNameHost` is null terminated, otherwise it would not work correctly with `printf`.

Comment: Oh, I actually read that example, but I'm not good at C and didn't know that printf requires null terminated string. Thanks, I'll follow your advise.